# Beanstalkd to start when the system starts up or reboots , how to uncomment "START yes" on Centos

Tags: linux, laravel, centos6, task-queue, beanstalkd

I'm using **Beanstalkd** for queue in Laravel on **Centos 6** and I have seen that I need to uncomment the following `START=yes` for  Beanstalkd to start when the system starts up or reboots

When I run this command  `nano /etc/default/beanstalkd` from root directory , I can't find the file. 
or let me if there is another way to enable that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For php to listen all times, You need to have **Supervisord** installed then do the following

- Locate this file **supervisord.conf** by running this command: `find / -name supervisord.conf`
- You get the path like this `/etc/supervisord.conf`
- Edit the file `sudo nano /etc/supervisord.conf`
- Make `autostart=true` and `autorestart=true`
- At bottom, have something like this

  `[program:laravel-queue-listener] command=php`

  `/var/www/YourProjectNameHere/artisan queue:listen --env=prod --timeout=0`
- Then restart supervisord: `sudo service supervisord restart`
- Restart beanstalkd too: `sudo service beanstalkd restart`

All Queues will be listened automatically without having to run `php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0` manually